# PedSelectOutput unhappy with false conditions on all 5 points

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to follow the Airport model creation in AnyLogic in 3 days book, phase 5 Defining the boarding logic.

As choose the pedSelectOutput1 to Use conditions  (as indicated on page 233 in the english version of the book) with Condition 1 returning a boolean and if true following the first flowchart, otherwise the second flowchart, I get an error. As the rest of the conditions are set false I guess the problem is that it gets stuck when all conditions return false? According to the article https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/selectoutput5.html if all conditions are false the agents goes out throw the 5th point. And my error message says "root.pedSelectOutput1: Agent can't leave the port root.pedSelectOutput1.out5: it has no connections."

So to fix the case when all conditions are false for the system not to get stuck, I need to connect at least one of the flows after the Ped Select Output block to its 5th point instead of the 2nd? Looks messy as I only have 2 flowcharts and they aren't visualized in a consequent order.

Is it how it works or there is a better way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 flow charts, simply use the `SelectOutput` block from the "Process Modelling library" instead (not `Ped Select Output`). Same logic but it only has 2 exits. No need to fake-connect the 5th port :)

PS: You can often use blocks from other libraries, especially the "Process Modelling library" has blocks that are very useful for other libraries as well. Mix'n'match is the hallmark of AnyLogic :)